# Nginx - Php subdirectory files keep redirecting to homepage

Tags: php, redirect, nginx

I cannot seem to find a solution that works for my situation online anywhere. My nginx is configured to use bigbluebutton as a default so i have set up mysql and php to use the big blue button location. I have successfully gotten the php info file to show in the root of the file, but if i put the file in the subdirectory i get redirected to the root. This does not happen with an html file within the subdirectory only .php files. Initially i would get a 404 on the php file in the subdirectory but now i turned on short tags (even if there are none used, and it redirects me to the root of big blue.. Im sorry i am so noob, any help is truly appreciated.

```
server {
 listen   80;
 server_name  **.**.***.**;

 access_log  /var/log/nginx/bigbluebutton.access.log;

 # Handle RTMPT (RTMP Tunneling).  Forwards requests
 # to Red5 on port 5080
  location ~ (/open/|/close/|/idle/|/send/|/fcs/) {
      proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5080;
      proxy_redirect     off;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

      client_max_body_size       10m;
      client_body_buffer_size    128k;

      proxy_connect_timeout      90;
      proxy_send_timeout         90;
      proxy_read_timeout         90;

      proxy_buffering            off;
      keepalive_requests         1000000000;
  }

 # Handle desktop sharing tunneling.  Forwards
 # requests to Red5 on port 5080.
   location /deskshare {
       proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5080;
       proxy_redirect     default;
       proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       client_max_body_size       10m;
       client_body_buffer_size    128k;
       proxy_connect_timeout      90;
       proxy_send_timeout         90;
       proxy_read_timeout         90;
       proxy_buffer_size          4k;
       proxy_buffers              4 32k;
       proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
       proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
       include    fastcgi_params;
   }

# BigBlueButton landing page.
    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;        
      root   /var/www/bigbluebutton-default;
      index index.php index.html index.htm;
  expires 1m;
    }

# Include specific rules for record and playback
    include /etc/bigbluebutton/nginx/*.nginx;

    error_page  404  /404.html;

    # Redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root   /var/www/nginx-default;
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME     
            $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;

    }
}
```

Comment: Please help... adding server location block with alias or root and various configurations are not working... i just keep getting redirected, there must be something im missing...

Comment: What is the name of the subdirectory? And what is the path to that subdirectory?

Comment: /kemsley  it is in the location /var/www/bigbluebutton-default/kemsley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't appear to have a `root` set for your `location ~ \.php$` block. If you have a common root for a number of `location` blocks, you should probably move the `root` directive up a level to the surrounding `server` block. Like this snippet:

```
root /var/www/bigbluebutton-default;

location / {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;        
    expires 1m;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    ...
}
```

Comment: YES!! MAGICAL!!!!! OH MY GOODNESSSS!!!!!!!!!! THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!!!